# how to add a table filter in the code snippets in javascript?

Tags: javascript, json, filter

Hi I already put all codes in the links but I do not know how to add filter for name:https://codepen.io/nutkin/pen/yLOmzom
The table was created from json object using loop in javascript,I could search a lot of answers about how to fix it in jquery or reactjs,but I really want to know how to fiddle this in javascript.
let me take a example:If the user key in 'F' or 'f',the screen should filter all name with 'f' and 'F',thanks every guys.Below is the code:

```js
var myContacts = [
    {category: "Sporting Goods", price: "$49.99", stocked: true, name: "Football"},
    {category: "Sporting Goods", price: "$9.99", stocked: true, name: "Baseball"},
    {category: "Sporting Goods", price: "$29.99", stocked: false, name: "Basketball"},
    {category: "Electronics", price: "$99.99", stocked: true, name: "iPod Touch"},
    {category: "Electronics", price: "$399.99", stocked: false, name: "iPhone 5"},
    {category: "Electronics", price: "$199.99", stocked: true, name: "Nexus 7"}
  ];
  function generateTable(){
    var table=document.createElement('table');
    table.style.width='50%';
   
    table.setAttribute('cellspacing','0');
    table.setAttribute('cellpading','5');
    var col=[];
    for(var i=0;i<myContacts.length;i++){
      for(var key in myContacts[i]){
        if(col.indexOf(key)===-1){
          col.push(key);
        }
      }
    }
    var tHead=document.createElement('thead');
    var hRow=document.createElement('tr');
    for(var i=col.length-3;i<col.length;i++)
      {
        if(col[i]!='stocked')
        {
          var th=document.createElement('th');
      th.innerHTML=col[i];
      hRow.appendChild(th);
      }    
      }
    tHead.appendChild(hRow);
    table.appendChild(tHead);

    var tBody=document.createElement('tbody');
    for(var i=0;i<myContacts.length;i++)
    {
      var bRow=document.createElement('tr');
      var y=document.createElement('td');
      var t=document.createTextNode(myContacts[i].name);
      y.appendChild(t);
     
      var z=document.createElement('tr');
      var s=document.createTextNode(myContacts[i].price);
      z.appendChild(s);
      bRow.appendChild(y);
      bRow.appendChild(z);
      tBody.appendChild(bRow);
      if(myContacts[i].stocked===false)
      {
        y.style.color='red';

      }
    }
   
    table.appendChild(tBody);
    var divContainer=document.getElementById('tableroom');
    divContainer.innerHTML='';
    divContainer.appendChild(table);
}
```

```html
<body onload="generateTable()">
  <input type="text"  name="search" id="searchBar" placeholder="Search..">  
  <div id='chechbox'>
      <input type="checkbox" id='searchBox'>Only show products in stock
  </div>
  <div id="tableroom" ></div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

something like that ?

```js
const myContacts = 
    [ { category: 'Sporting Goods', price: "$49.99",  stocked: true,  name: "Football"   } 
    , { category: 'Sporting Goods', price: "$9.99",   stocked: true,  name: "Baseball"   } 
    , { category: 'Sporting Goods', price: '$29.99',  stocked: false, name: 'Basketball' } 
    , { category: 'Electronics',    price: '$99.99',  stocked: true,  name: 'iPod Touch' } 
    , { category: 'Electronics',    price: '$399.99', stocked: false, name: 'iPhone 5'   } 
    , { category: 'Electronics',    price: '$199.99', stocked: true,  name: 'Nexus 7'    } 
    ] 

const info = 
  { room : document.getElementById('tableroom')
  , table : null
  };
const chkOnlyStock = document.getElementById('chk-onlyStock')
  ,   searchBar    = document.getElementById('search-bar')
  ;
(function() // IIFE generateTable
  {
  let eTable = document.createElement('table')

  myContacts.forEach(contact=>
    {
    let row = eTable.insertRow()

    let c_Name  = row.insertCell()
    c_Name.textContent = contact.name
    c_Name.className   = contact.stocked ? '' : 'noStock'

    row.insertCell().textContent = contact.price
    })

  let rowHead = eTable.createTHead().insertRow()
  rowHead.insertCell().textContent = 'Name'
  rowHead.insertCell().textContent = 'Price'
  
  info.room.appendChild(eTable)
  info.table = info.room.querySelector('tbody')
  })()

function rowShow()
  {
  let showAll = (searchBar.value === '')
  if (/^[a-zA-Z]+$/.test(searchBar.value)  || showAll )  // accept only characters
    {
    let reg = new RegExp(searchBar.value, 'ig')
      ; 
    info.table.querySelectorAll('tr').forEach(row=>
      {
      let stockOk   = !(chkOnlyStock.checked && row.cells[0].classList.contains('noStock'))
        , letterOK  = reg.test(row.cells[0].textContent)
        ;
      reg.lastIndex = 0;
      row.className = (( letterOK || showAll) && stockOk) ? '' : 'noDisplay'
      })
    }
  else searchBar.value = '' // otherwise reset!
  }

chkOnlyStock.onchange = rowShow
searchBar.oninput     = rowShow
```

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  margin: .5em;
}
thead {
  font-weight: bold;
  background-color: #978aec;
  text-align: center;
}
td {
  padding: .2em .7em;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
td:nth-of-type(2)  {
  text-align: right;
}
.noStock {
  color: red;
}
.noDisplay {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<input type="text"  name="search" id="search-bar" placeholder="Search..">  
<br>
<label> <input type="checkbox" id='chk-onlyStock'>Only show products in stock </label>
<br>
<div id="tableroom"></div>
```